# Proving that $(2x + 1)^2\equiv -3 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My teacher proposed the following exercise:

> Let $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ be an odd prime number. Prove that $\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right) = 1$

I was able to prove this using some properties of the Legendre symbol. However, my teacher left the following suggestion under the exercise:

> (Suggestion: Start by showing that if $x$ is an element of $U(\mathbb Z_p)$ with order $3$, then $(2x+1)^2\equiv -3\pmod p$)

After doing the exercise my way, I came back and tried to prove that my teacher suggested, but I have no idea why $(2x + 1)^2$ would be congruent to $-3$.

How can this be done?

Comment: Hint: if $x\pmod p$ has order $3$ then $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod p$.

Comment: why is that the case @lulu? the sums of the members of a subgroup of $U(\mathbb Z_p)$ sum to zero?

Comment: $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field, so every element of order $3$ in the multiplicative group is a root of one factor of $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ or the other.  We can rule out $x-1$ (why?) and that leaves the quadratic factor.

Comment: HINT: $$(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1\equiv-3\pmod p\iff4(x^2+x+1)\equiv0\pmod p$$ Why $(x^2+x+1)\equiv0\pmod p$?